# Ajax post call throwing an error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I am trying to make a post call through ajax from my front end to my express server, but I am getting the error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME. The code for ajax is below

```js
function sendSteps(encodedLatLangs) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost:3000/route',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "jsonp; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain:true,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            steps: encodedLatLangs
        }),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(done);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            console.log('Ajax call gave an error');
        }
    })};
```

My console is showing this.
[image]

This is how I am handling post request to this endpoint on backend

```js
router.post('/route',function (req, res) {
    
    console.log("Hello Received the Data");
    res.send("Hello Received the Data");
    //Doing something with the received data
});
```

Can some throw any light on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in response header.
Something like this. For more details visit https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html
And also we have to remove "data type" and "content type" from the ajax request.

```js
router.route('/route')
    .post((req, res, next) => {
        controllers
            .post(req.body)
            .then(data => {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
                res.send(message.generateMessage(200, '', data))
            })
            .catch(err => next(err))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

With JSONP you can sending only **GET** request (JSONP insert `script` tags into the DOM).

Your `data` should be a `&key=value` string and `contentType` is `application/javascript`

Try it:

```
function sendSteps(encodedLatLangs) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost:3000/route',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/javascript; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: 'steps=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(encodedLatLangs)),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(done);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log('Ajax call gave an error');
        }
    });
};
```

Or use JSON (if you are a server owner and can set up CORS).

Comment: @SiddharthSinha Of course, you have other mistakes ;) 1) `router.post` for POST request, you have GET request (see your screenshot). 2) In the case of JSONP, your server must return javascript with execute of registered callback-function. Etc.